# Logs inverted in Javascript

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm writing some tests with `casperjs` and I came across something really strange to me :

here is the code :

```
casper.test.begin('Test', nbTests, function(test) {
    console.log(A_SERVER + A_IMPORT + A_IMPORT_TAB1);
    casper.start(A_SERVER + A_IMPORT + A_IMPORT_TAB1);    
    casper.waitForUrl(A_SERVER + A_IMPORT + A_IMPORT_TAB1, function (){
        console.log("ok");
    }, function(){
        console.log("nok");
    });
    console.log(casper.getCurrentUrl());
    casper.run(function(){
        test.done();
        this.exit();
    });
});
```

The test runs fine, but logs are displayed this way :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/import/upload/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/import/upload/
ok
```

Could you tell me why are the two last logs inverted ? I guess it is related to how functions are handled with `javascript`, but I'd like a more explicit explaination.

Comment: Because `casper.waitForUrl` is asynchronous, and the `console.log('ok');` is the callback which is executed after that function.

Comment: It is specific to `casperjs`, but asynchronous functions are very common in js.

Comment: As @Rob says, it's run asynchronously, not just a JS thing, this applies to any asynchronous code, can be any language really.

And yes, same code can be written to be Synchronous, it's just the things are implemented, and there's a good reason they were implemented that way

Comment: Just one last question : are all anonymous functions asynchronous in javascript ?

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg I don't discuss the utility, I just didn't know this, hence my uncomprehension and my question.

Comment: Yeah I understand, I just blurt out extra info just in case ;), and no not all anonymous functions are async, you'll need to look into the way they're implemented to see, some will be, some won't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.waitForUrl()` creates a background job and returns. When the response from the remote server arrives, it will call the callback function. That is why you see the synchronous

```
console.log(casper.getCurrentUrl());
```

first.

> are all anonymous functions asynchronous in javascript ?

No. Read the documentation of the frameworks that you use to learn which callbacks are called when.

Generally, many anonymous functions are asynchronous since they are used as event handlers (will only be called once the event happens) or processing AJAX responses (asynchronous by nature).